# Saving and displaying user answers from multiple choice form

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a list field which contains questions in the first screen and I am passing the selected index of the list to the second screen I am parsing JSON according to the question id. I am parsing the answers for the questions. The question will be 2 types such as single answer and multiple answer. I am displaying an array of Radio button field for single answers and a array of Checkbox field for multiple answers.

If the user selects the answer, I need to store it temporarily and I should show him the answer which he selected when he selects the same question. I don't have idea in this. Can any one guide me in this? I need to do it using sqlite?

Comment: When you say you need to store the data temporarily, how temporary do you mean? Is it acceptable to lose the user's answer when he/she exits the app?  What about restarting the device?  There are different levels of storage on BlackBerry, depending on how long your data needs to stay around.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue: Temporary means, till the user click the submit button and the datas has to get uploaded in the server, the datas has to be stored.

Comment: And if the device is restarted before the user clicks 'submit' do you need to keep track of the data?

Comment: @MichaelDonohue: yes. I have to

Comment: Thanks all. I have figured out with sqlite db. Solved my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Persistent object in BlackBerry. Here is a code sample demonstrates the example to use the  [persistent-object-in-blackberry](http://www.codinguru.com/2011/09/persistent-object-in-blackberry.html)